# $[G:H]=4$ where $H\neq 1$ means that $G$ is not simple.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, normal-subgroups, simple-groups

The question is as follows:

> Suppose $G$ is a finite group with a nontrivial subgroup of index $4$. Prove that $G$ is not simple.

I am on the hunt for a non-trivial normal subgroup. This proof followed a proof of Cayley's theorem, so it is likely that is involved. So if $|G|=n$ and  $\phi_g: G \to G$ is defined by $\phi_g (x) =g\cdot x.$ Then $\phi_g \in S_G$ so that $\psi: G\to S_G$ defined by $\psi (g) = \phi_g$ is an embedding (pretty much an outline of Cayleys thm). This helps us in some way, but I am unsure how.  My mental summary of the sitch says that I have a subgroup of $S_n$ that is the "same shape" as $G$, call it Im$\psi$. But Im$\psi$ also has a non-trivial subgroup of index $4$, call it $H$, and this subgroup is a group of permutations of the set of $n$ elements. Overall, we have that $[\text{Im}\psi :H]=4$ and $|\text{Im}\psi|$ divides $n!$ All of this (and perhaps something else I am missing), tells me that Im$\psi$ has a non-trivial normal subgroup.

In general, I feel that I have to exhibit a map from Im$\psi$ to *some other group that I am unsure of* with nontrivial kernel.

In hindsight, perhaps Cayleys theorem was misleading: if $[G:H]=4$ and $A=\left\{xH: x\in G \right\}$ can I just talk about the map $$\rho: G\to A$$ defined by $$\rho (g) = gH$$ and hope to goodness gracious that it is a homormorphism? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $A$ is not a group unless $H$ is normal... which you do not know. Instead, use the *idea* of Cayley's Theorem by letting $G$ *act* on $A$ by $a\cdot(gH) = agH$. Use it to define a morphism $G\to S_4$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin right so youre saying that I would not be able to use the isomorphism theorems as I was hoping to.

Comment: I'm saying you can't use your set $A$ as the target of a "homomorphism", because it may not even be a group at all.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Also why morphism and not homomorphism in your last sentence?

Comment: They are the same thing.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin so the group is acting on the set of the (four) cosets of $H$ correct? And thus we can say that the group acts on a subgroup of permutations of four elements?

Comment: The group doesn't "act on a subgroup of permutations of four elements". The action defines a homomorphism from $G$ *to* a subgroup of the permutation group $S_4$.

Comment: BTW, there is no need to assume that the subgroup is nontrivial.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I have updated the post with a proof, based on your hints; if you have any feedback it would be much appreciated. I used Sylow which felt heavy handed. Is there a proof without the sylow theorems?

Comment: If you have an answer, then it should be posted as an answer (yes, even an answer to your own question).

Answer (score 3):

**Hints.**

- As said in the comments, use the action of $G$ on $G/H$ to define a group morphism $\psi:G\to S_4$.

Justify that $\psi$ is non trivial.

- If $G$ is simple, deduce that $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup $G'$ of $S_4$ , and that the order of this subgroup is a multiple of $4$.
- Justify that $\vert G'\vert =4,8,12$.
- Using a property of $p$-groups ($p$ prime), rule out $4$ and $8$ (you may also want to identify subgroups of order $4$ and $8$ of $S_4$ if you do not know anything about $p$-groups)
- If $G'$ has order $12$, what is $G'$ ?
- Conclude that $G$ is not simple.

Comment: There's no need to add an assumption "If $G$ is simple". If $\psi$ is not one-to-one, then its kernel gives you a non-trivial normal subgroup. Otherwise, you can proceed as you do.

Comment: I have updated the post with a proof, based on your hints; if you have any feedback it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

*Proof*: Suppose $[G:H]=4$ and $|G|>4$ and let $$A=\left\{xH: x\in G \right\}$$ Notice that each $g\in G$ induces the action $g\cdot (xH) =(gx)H$ on $A$. In particular, $\sigma_g : A\to A$ defined by $\sigma_g (xH) = g\cdot (xH)$ is a permutation. Thus $\phi: G\to S_A \cong S_4$ defined by $\phi (g) = \sigma_g$ is a group homomorphism. Edit: Further, if $\phi$ is not injective then we would have that $1 <\text{ker}\phi \triangleleft G$ so that $G$ is not simple. If $\phi$ *is* injective, in the spirit of Cayley,  $$G\cong \text{Im} \phi \leqslant S_A \cong S_4. $$ Let Im$\phi =G'$. Then $|G'|$ divides $4! =24$. But since $G$ is finite, so is $G'$. Further, we know there is some $H'$ such that $[G':H']=4$ Hence, $|H'|=|G'|/4$. This means that $$ |H'| \in \left\{2,3\right\} $$ If $|H'|=2$ then $|G'|=8=2^3$ which we know not to be simple as it is a $p$-group with $n>1$. If $|H'| =3$, then $|G'|=2^2\cdot 3$. Now $n_3 =1\lor 4$. If $n_3=1$ then we found our nontrivial normal subgroup and we are donzo. If $n_3=4$ then there are $8$ nonidentity elements, leaving just enough room for our unique, therefore normal, Sylow $2$-subgroup of order 4. Hence, in either case, $G'$ isn't simple so that neither is $G$. $\nsim$

Comment: It is not the elements of $G$ that "induce an action". The elements give a permutation. The way to phrase it is that "Note that $G$ acts on $A$ by $g\cdot(xh) = (gx)H$. This gives a group homomorphism $\phi\colon G\to S_A\cong S_4$." (Assuming you know that group actions correspond to homomorphisms into permutation groups).

Comment: You do not know that $G\cong\mathrm{Im}\phi$, because you have not assumed or established that $\phi$ is one-to-one.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Now that you mention it, I'm not even sure if it *is* injective. I got to $(xt)H=(yt)H$ but it seems unlikely I can get from here to $x=y$

Comment: You don't know if it is injective. But if it is not injective, what can you tell about its kernel?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin besides these is the proof sufficient?

Comment: You need to note that $\ker\phi\leq H$ to justify that $\ker\phi\neq G$ (otherwise, knowing that $\ker\phi$ is nontrivial does not prove $G$ is simple... why is it not equal to all of $G$?) You also need that to justify that $G'$ has a subgroup of index $4$. "Since $G$ is finite, so is $G'$"... $G'$ is a subgroup of $S_4$; *of course* it's finite. I don't see how you conclude that $|H'|$ must be $2$ or $3$. Why can't $G'$ have order $24$, in which case $H'$ would have order $6$? For instance, that happens if you *start* with $G=S_4$ and, say, $H=S_3$.

Comment: Okay I understand why ker$\phi \leqslant H$ is needed to say ker$\phi \triangleleft G$. But isnt showing that $G\cong G'$ perfectly enough to say that if $G$ has a subgroup of index $4$ so does $G'$? And you are right $|H'|=6$ is a perfectly good possibility. But the same argument used for $|H'|=3$ can be used here to prove that $G$ must not be simple.

Comment: I didn't say you couldn't fix it. You asked if what you had was sufficient. It wasn't. And you don't need the kernel to be contained in $H$ to show it is normal. You need it to show it's a proper subgroup.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin forgive me. The last sentence was mostly me vocalizing my thoughts rather than any sort of rebuttal to what you were saying . And I was intentionally using $\triangleleft$ rather than $\trianglelefteq$. i.e. I understand that the kernel is always normal and the kernel being inside of $H$ tells us that it is proper. Any other bugs in the proof? Again, thank you for all of your help.